# How to eliminate white noise when using a MIDI keyboard

Tags: sound, midi, noise, audacity

I am experiencing some crackling sounds coming from my computer when I have qjackctl hooked up and I am using `zynaddsubfx`. At first I thought it was the microphone but I tested it with and without `qjackctl` hooked up and with just my voice it sounds fine. The problem I am experiencing is when I am playing on my MIDI keyboard and using `zynaddsubfx`.It seems like the problem is minor when just using `zynaddsubfx` and is exacerbated when I turn on Audacity.

To fix it I tried:

```
vi /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Then I typed these commands:

```
load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=0 tsched=0
load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=0
load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=0
```

Then, after restarting the computer I changed the microphone options, more were available.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I was right, it had to do with `qjackctl`. These were the settings I had with crackling sounds and white noise:

[image: ALSA 1]

[image: Audio 1]

And these are the correct settings that completely cleared up the problem:

[image: ALSA 2]

[image]

I found the answer to my question when I saw a comment that yoshimi was quieter. But after watching [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtO8BVJ0A0o) I decided to try and do the settings differently in `zynaddsubfx` and see if it made a difference.